CKeditor nested context menu does not show up properly
I am using CKEditor 4.16.2 with api:
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

I am trying to do a nested menu. When I clicked the "Translate" there must be one more menu but instead of getting a menu I got this visual bug:

It seems like the the nested menu is created but does not show up properly.
Here is my code:
CKEDITOR.replace('metinAlani', {
                on: {
                    instanceReady: function (evt) {
                        var editor = evt.editor;
                        editor.addMenuGroup('customGroup');
                        editor.addMenuItem('customItem',
                            {
                                label: 'Get Summary',
                                command: 'getSummary',
                                group: 'customGroup',
                            }
                        );
                        editor.addMenuItem('customItem2',
                            {
                                label: 'Get Question',
                                command: 'getQuestion',
                                group: 'customGroup',
                            }
                        );
                        editor.addMenuItem('customItem3', {
                            label: 'Translate',
                            command: 'translateCommand',
                            group: 'customGroup',
                            getItems: function () {
                                var items = {};
                                items['translateOption1'] = {
                                    label: 'Option 1',
                                    command: 'translateOption1Command'
                                };
                                items['translateOption2'] = {
                                    label: 'Option 2',
                                    command: 'translateOption2Command'
                                };
                                return items;
                            }
                        });
                        editor.addCommand('getSummary', {
                            exec: function (editor) {
                                document.querySelector("button[value='first_action']").click();
                            }
                        });
                        editor.addCommand('getQuestion', {
                            exec: function (editor) {
                                document.querySelector("button[value='second_action']").click();
                            }
                        });
                        editor.addCommand('translateCommand', {
                            exec: function (editor) {
                                console.log('Translate command executed');
                            }
                        });
                        editor.addCommand('translateOption1Command', {
                            exec: function (editor) {
                                console.log('Translate Option 1 command executed');
                            }
                        });
                        editor.addCommand('translateOption2Command', {
                            exec: function (editor) {
                                console.log('Translate Option 2 command executed');
                            }
                        });

                        editor.contextMenu.addListener(function (element) {
                            var items = {};
                            items['customItem'] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                            items['customItem2'] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                            items['customItem3'] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF;
                            return items;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

Is there any problem that I can not find?
